# AngularJS: Get Url before redirect

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, transition

I have a state defined for all wrong Urls

```
.state('404', { 
    url: '/404',
    data: { title: 'Page not found' },
    templateUrl: errorHandlerTemplate,
    parent: 'authenticated' 
})
```

I have a redirect set up to make it work

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/404');
```

I want to get the original Url that the user tried to enter before the redirect happened.

```
$transitions.onBefore({ entering: '404' }, function(trans) {
    console.log(trans.from().name);
    console.log(trans.to().name);
});
```

'**trans.to().name**' always seems to hold the value '404' which is the final Url after the redirect. Is there a way to get the original Url that was discarded?

Comment: If the UI router made the redirect, then there is a possibility of getting the previous URL. If the server made the redirect, then there's no chance. Can you clarify?

Comment: '$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/404')' is the redirection on the client side

Answer (score 0):

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, options) {
    console.log(fromState, fromParams);
}
```

`$stateChangeStart` is fired when the transition begins

`fromState` and `fromParams` are enough to get the url before redirection.

[For more info on $stateChangeStart](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events)

Comment: The use of $rootScope has been deprecated by $transitions service. You do have an onBefore event, but the 'from' and 'to' show the last valid Url and the '/404' respectively. The invalid Url being redirected to /404 is eaten up in between

Comment: Why do you want that invalid url?!